# Is it possible to generate three independent noraml r.v.s out of two

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two independent standard normal r.v.s. Does there exist a function $f=f(x,y)$ such that $(X,Y,f(X,Y))$ is independent standard normal?
If not, how about the existence of functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ such that $(f_1(X,Y),f_2(X,Y),f_3(X,Y))$ is independent normal?

Thanks!

Comment: can $f_i$ be any functions? :-) then probably yes. must $f_i$ be measurable? then not.

Comment: do you have a counter-example? I believe it is not possible but I do not have a  proof right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: no.  Second question, yes, and the $f_i$ need only depend on their first argument alone, just for laughs.  Here is one construction:
  First, let $U= \Phi(X)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal c.d.f.  The r.v. $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.   Second, let $B_n$ be the
$n$-th bit in the binary expansion of $U$.  Third, let
$U_i = \sum_{k \equiv i \pmod{3}} B_n 2^{-(k-i)/3}$ be the binary number formed by taking every third bit of $U$, on the bit positions congruent  $i$ mod 3.  (The 3 numbers $U_i$ are also uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and independent.) And finally, let $f_i(X) = \Phi^{-1}(U_i)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！！ Do you have a short proof on why the answer to the first question is false? I guess, asking for, say, (f(X,Y),g(X,Y),Y) to be indep normal is also not possible?  Also, from your construction, it seems that those f_i s are not measurable. If we restrict to measurable functions, is the answer to the 2nd question still true? Thanks and look forward to your reply~

Comment: In your first question, you need to make the conditional variance of $f(X,Y)$ given $X$ and $Y$ equal that of $Z$ given $X$ and $Y$.  The former works out to 0 and the latter to 1.

Comment: As for your new question about  $(f(X,Y),g(X,Y),Y)$, I think the same sort of method will work.  And as for measurability: yes, the functions $f_i$ are measurable, being built up out of measurable pieces, like composition of continuous functions, summation of convergent series, and of binary digits. The function mapping a number in $[0,1]$ to its $n$-th binary digit, for example, is measurable.  Its inverse images, for instance, are all finite unions of intervals.